# Nexus3: How to persist docker data in ec2?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, nexus3

I am running this on an EC2 machine that has EBS volume attached to it.

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --name registry --publish 5000:5000 --publish 8081:8081 sonatype/nexus3:3.6.2
```

Now how do I persist the nexus data into EBS volume? So even if something bad happens my data persist.

Comment: General solution: - mount the directory that is mapped to the EBS volume into the container. - Either configure nexus to persist its data to the mounted directory or mount the directory to the path where nexus would persist its data.

Comment: I have two questions 1. when we attach EBS volume it gets attach to /dev/xvda. so I need to mount /dev/xvda to nexus path.

2. Command to mount the path in docker swam is same as that of docker?